# slow ajax script. AJAX, PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am creating a forum kind of website where users can post something. So, there are two buttons for every post, 'genuine' and 'dubious'. [image]

when the genuine button is clicked there should be a dynamic change of genuine count below Date and Time, and also on the button. The button should also get disabled after clicking it. I am using ajax to do this dynamically which communicates with php and makes changes in mysql database. It is working fine but the problem is, if i click the button very fast more than once the script is running two or three times i.e the genuine count is increasing twice or thrice. Is there anything to avoid this?

---

**code for displaying buttons**

```
$query="select * from genuineposts where username='$username' and pid='$postid' ";
$sql=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
    //the user has clicked genuine

    echo "<span id='genuinespan3".$row['id']."' name='genuinespan3".$row['id']."'><button name='genuinebutton3".$row['id']."' id='genuinebutton3".$row['id']."' onclick='genuine3(".$row['id'].")' disabled>
        Genuine[ ".$row['genuine']." ]"."</button></span>&nbsp";
    echo "<span id='undogenuinespan3".$row['id']."' name='undogenuinespan3".$row['id']."'><button name='undogenuinebutton3".$row['id']."' id='undogenuinebutton3".$row['id']."'onclick='undogenuine3(".$row['id'].")' >undo</button></br></span>";
    echo "</br>";
    echo "<span id='dubiousspan3".$row['id']."' name='dubiousspan3".$row['id']."'></span>&nbsp";
    echo "<span id='undodubiousspan3".$row['id']."' name='undodubiousspan3".$row['id']."'></span>";
    exit();
}else{

    //check if he clicked dubious
    $query="select * from dubiousposts where username='$username' and pid='$postid' ";
    $sql=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql)>0){
        //the user clicked dubious
        echo "<span id='genuinespan2".$row['id']."' name='genuinespan2".$row['id']."'></span>&nbsp";
        echo "<span id='undogenuinespan2".$row['id']."' name='undogenuinespan2".$row['id']."'></span>";
        echo "</br>";
        echo "<span name='dubiousspan2".$row['id']."' id='dubiousspan2".$row['id']."'> <button name='dubiousbutton2".$row['id']."' id='dubiousbutton2".$row['id']."' onclick='dubious2(".$row['id'].")' disabled>
             Dubious[ ".$row['dubious']." ]"."</button></span>&nbsp";

        echo "<span id='undodubiousspan2".$row['id']."' name='undodubiousspan2".$row['id']."'><button name='undodubiousbutton2".$row['id']."'
                    id='undodubiousbutton2".$row['id']."' onclick='undodubious2(".$row['id'].")'>undo</button></span></br>";

        exit();
    }
else{

    //the user has not clicked either genuine or dubious

    echo "<span id='genuinespan1".$row['id']."' name='genuinespan1".$row['id']."'><button name='genuinebutton1".$row['id']."' id='genuinebutton1".$row['id']."' onclick='genuine1(".$row['id'].")' >
        Genuine[ ".$row['genuine']." ]"."</button></span>&nbsp";


    echo "<span id='undogenuinespan1".$row['id']."' name='undogenuinespan1".$row['id']."'></span>";

    echo "</br>";

    echo "<span id='dubiousspan1".$row['id']."' name='dubiousspan1".$row['id']."'><button name='dubiousbutton1".$row['id']."' id='dubiousbutton1".$row['id']."' onclick='dubious1(".$row['id'].")' >
        Dubious[ ".$row['dubious']." ]"."</button></span>&nbsp";


    echo "<span id='undodubiousspan1".$row['id']."' name='undodubiousspan1".$row['id']."'></span></br>";

}
}
```

Comment: Record the user id/username somewhere to indicate that he has voted genuine.. and every time someone votes..check if he has already voted or not.

Comment: When are you disabling the button? You should do it immediately after the click, sounds like you're doing it after the response is received. Either way, you're going to need to show your code in order to get some real help.

Comment: disable the "Genuine" button after the click. so that you are not able to click on it doubles.You should do it immediately after the click.

Comment: yes i am disabling it.. but the problem is it is running slow.. you can see the code above now